# How to extract file name from file path with sscanf_s()?

Tags: c, scanf

I want to extract file name `License.xml` from the string through function `sscanf_s`

```
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="C:\share\file1\License.xml"
```

Currently, I just know to match the whole file name by

```
char file_name[256] = {""};
sscanf_s( line, "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"%s\"", file_name);
```

As for how to extract the `License.xml` from file name, I do not know how to do that?

From this [doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx), I did not find any useful information to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char *line ="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"C:\\share\\file1\\License.xml\"";
char file_name[256] = {""};
char *p;
sscanf_s( line, "%*s %*s %*s filename=\"%[^\"]\"", file_name, sizeof(file_name));
p = strrchr(file_name, '\\')+1;
memmove(file_name, p, strlen(p)+1);
puts(file_name);//License.xml
```